# Error on startup of activiti-rest

Tags: activiti

On startup of activiti-rest 5.16.4 we get the following error, our older instance 15.4 is working without problems:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.activiti.rest.servlet.WebConfigurer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/DispatcherType
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2842)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.DispatcherType
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 32 more
```

We use tomcat 6.0.39 and JRE 1.7.0_65-b32 on our hosted servers.

Do we miss a library or have a configuration problem? Or is it related to Spring 4? Or is activiti 5.16 not compatible with tomcat 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DispatcherType was introduced in Servlet spec 3.0 as far as I now.
If you look at the Tomcat version support table here: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

You will see that Tomcat 6 supports servlet spec 2.5, so this is most likely the cause of your class not found error.

Upgrade to Tomcat 7 and I reckon you'll be golden.

Cheers,
Greg

Comment: Thanks for the comparison matrix. We will contact our isp :)